# jquery live event gets executed twice

Tags: jquery

I am loading content into a page with ajax that will have live click events attached to them.  It seems like the first time  I load this content everything works as expected.  If I load this again, the events fire twice (when put breakpoints in the code).  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way I can clear the dom of these elements before they get loaded again?

Comment: My crystal ball is not available right now, maybe you can post your code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I guess you're calling `.live()` on the same elements again and again.
use `.die()` on those elements before calling `.live()`.

Answer (score 23):

I fixed it like this:

```
$('selector').die('click').live('click', function () {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 3):

just confirmed.  Was using .live() and experimented with .unbind() first.

final:

```
$(".clickedClass").die("click").live("click", function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ON method instead of live. THEN

jQuery('body').unbind().on('submit', 'form.make_commitment_form',function(e) { .... });